# SQL : programmatically determine if table is view

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I need to determine if a given table is a view, can I do this with a query instead of using '\d' ? I have a script that needs to audit several tables for deletion but don't want to check them all manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [pg_class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalog-pg-class.html):

> relkind   char
>
> r = ordinary table, i = index, S = sequence, v = view, m = materialized view, c = composite type, t = TOAST table, f = foreign table

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT relname 
           FROM pg_class
           WHERE relname='<object_name>' 
            AND relkind = 'v') 
THEN
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find that information from the [information_schema.tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-tables.html) view:

```
select table_type 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'my_schema' and table_name = 'my_table'
```

`table_type` column description:

> Type of the table: BASE TABLE for a persistent base table (the normal table type), VIEW for a view, FOREIGN TABLE for a foreign table, or LOCAL TEMPORARY for a temporary table